# How to access mongoose populated fields?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I'm not able to access the populated fields of mongoose objects. I want to output it in my page.

Example:

"console.log(booking.assignedUser.first)"   gives me back:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')

But from what I can tell, this should be working. The field is clearly there.
[image]

In my jsx file:

```
console.log(booking.assignedUser)
```

[image]
Object:

```
{
  etc etc

  assignedUser: { _id: new ObjectId("62f068b068802d58c8d35442"), first: 'driver' },
  etc etc
}
```

So why I can access booking.assignedUser and it shows me the data, but booking.assignedUser.first doesn't work?

Comment: Try optional chaining. It might be undefined first, and then the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because these values are being populated from the DB, I guess they aren't loading fast enough so it's giving me this error.

If I check to make sure the value exists first, then use it, it's working.

I'm working with a lot of this type of data in my app, so instead of outputting the jsx directly in the react object, I'm using a function to return it all for me which I pass in the db data.

using a ternary at the beginning of the output within the React component was not good enough, for example.

```
{ data ?
<Form>
  <SomeStuffHere>
  <SomeMoreStuffHere>
  <Form.Control> {data.something} </Form.Control>
</Form>
: '' }
```

This was not good enough. It would still error out. I had to place the ternary immediately on the field in order for it to work.

Doing this for every single field would be a pain in the ass, so putting it into a function first seems to work better.